# How to create duplicate image in visual basic 6

Tags: image, vb6, copy, element, basic

I have a problem in Visual Basic 6.
I have two forms in a project and when I click on Image1 in Form 1 then Form2 is showing up. Form2 contains a Button which build a Image when it's clicked. Then Image2 properties must be equal to Image1 properties.
I have the below code but it's not working so far.

`Dim obj2 As Image
obj2 = Form1.Node
obj2.Left = Form2.Xpos
obj2.Top = Form2.ypos`

Comment: Corrected spelling and grammar.

Comment: Which error does occur?